# How to activate syntax coloring for javascript in JSP editor - Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp, syntax-highlighting

there are situations when javascript really has to be in a JSP page, instead of having it in a separate files.

And some frameworks also do some things with Javascripts so that they have user to include it into JSP tags, so that JS is not in `<script src...>` but `<some:jspTag>`

I'd like to know if it is possible to setup formatting for it, it works in `<script src...>` but not in `<some:jspTag>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to figure out the same  thing, because Liferay  tag does this thing. Unfortunately it is not possible, at least a year ago it wasn't.

[eclipse forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=166961)

Comment: Hech, that's exactly what I need it for too. It's a damn problem, it makes the work very hard, because not only syntax coloring is gone, but even other basic support.