# Editing text/html content in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, formatting

I'm getting more into using javascript-rendered templates by wrapping them in 'script type="text/html"' tags (in my case within a JSP). The problem is that Eclipse (Indigo) doesn't apply any formatting such as syntax colouring, indentation, suggestions, etc. Is there a way that i can tell Eclipse to treat such content as HTML?

(Edit)

Thanks to folks for the answers, but perhaps i should clarify the question. JSP editing in Eclipse works quite well - just a few nuisances here and there. Different formats within the JSP including JSP, Javascript, HTML, and scriptlets work fine. I just wondered whether there was a configuration somewhere where i could define a **<script type="text/html">** section to be rendered as HTML. If the answer is no, so be it.

Comment: This question seems like a duplicate from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211841/is-there-a-good-jsp-editor-for-eclipse Try this link out.

Comment: For people who have just answered : The OP is not looking for an Editor for JS/HTML standalone files rather the need is for a JSP Editor that handles Javascript content inside a jsp file properly.

Comment: +1 good question. I'd like this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be possible to get specific content (Javascript) inside a JSP to get syntax colored. Check this : [How to activate syntax coloring for javascript in JSP editor - Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697958/how-to-activate-syntax-coloring-for-javascript-in-jsp-editor-eclipse)

Also, this might be useful : [Is there a good JSP editor for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211841/is-there-a-good-jsp-editor-for-eclipse)

The Amateras Editor in the answer above is available here:
http://sourceforge.jp/projects/amateras/downloads/51002/tk.eclipse.plugin.htmleditor_2.1.0.jar and must be downloaded and manually installed to the plugins folder.

I just tried it on Indigo SR2 and it contributes an Editor for JSP Files. I do not have a sufficiently complex JSP file to test it out, but from the code that I tested it on, the syntax coloring doesn't seem to be wildly different from the 'JSP Editor' contribute by Eclipse **[Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)**.

**Snapshots**
[image]

See the above snapshot in it's full size here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/es0OJ.png

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh. The Eclipse forum link is a couple years old now, but in the absence of any other information i guess it's a no-can-do. Workaround for now is to temporarily ctrl+shift+C the script tags, which causes the sections to format as desired.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm very late but in case someone runs into this with the same problem, like me

I didn't want to use any plugins and I finally came up with a simple workaround for our particular case of using JSP: using the JSTL command 'out'

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<c:out value=" <script id='emptyTemplate' type='text/template'> " escapeXml="false" />

    <div class="emptyTemplateDiv">
        Nothing here
    </div>

<c:out value=" </script> " escapeXml="false" ></c:out>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a plugin for Eclipse. Such as this [one](http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=EclipseHTMLEditor).

Answer (score 0):

Aptana Studio 3 .. Download and Install..

Select a theme. Enjoy JS